# Вынос строки подключения к БД в appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Не получается вынести строку подключения к БД из кода. Если закомментировать подключение в `MyDbContext.OnConfiguring()`

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    //...

}
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public MyDbContext()
{
    Database.EnsureCreated();
}

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{ }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    //if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    //{
    //    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=xx.xx.x.xxx;Initial Catalog=xx;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False");
    //}
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{    
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=xx.xxx.x.xxx;Initial Catalog=xx;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False"
    }
}
```

то в конструкторе `MyDbContext()` вылетает `Exception`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же в `ConfigureServices()` сделал соответствующие настроки, что не хватает?

Comment: Эм, а почему вы попадаете на parameterless конструктор? А главное - откуда? Из репозитория, у которого зависимость MyDbContext на конструкторе? Делали `services.AddTransient<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();` в `startup.cs`?

Comment: @AK, спасибо что обратил мое внимание на это. Да действительно у меня в одном из мест кода было место, где я не через IoC инстанировал `MyDbContext` и с помощью конструктора без параметров.